# Integrating 3rd party C++ compilers with Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

***Duplicate issue:*** I have read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036238/how-to-integrate-c-compiler-in-visual-studio-2008) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628914/integrating-a-custom-compiler-with-the-visual-studio-ide) and these didn't quite answer my question.
***Question:***: Is there a way I could make Visual Studio use g++ or comeau or other as the C++ compiler. If 
so, has anyone tried it? Any feedback?
***Reason:*** Love microsoft's IDE, hate their compiler.

Comment: Just curious: what's the problem with MS compiler?

Comment: @Henrik: Mainly multiple standards-incompliance issues and other MULTIPLE BUGS. I would be very thankful if my attitude (and its justifiedness) to Microsoft C++ compiler were not discussed in this thread. Thank you.

Comment: @Henrik: That it, about 15 years after the introduction of two-phase lookup, _still_ doesn't do this properly, making your write code that will not compile with any other compiler (nor with VC, should it ever catch up on that)?

Comment: @sbi: please guys, I really don't want this thread to become a vc++ mocking thread :)

Comment: @Armen: What's wrong with a good MS-bashing? `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Oh, understand me correctly, I LOVE MS-bashing (no, sorry, MS VC++ bashing mainly), I just don't want this particular thread to become the battlefield. How about a community wiki on that subject? I'd gladly participate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, Leor Zolman's stlfilt used to provide a drop-in replacement for `cl.exe`. However, that behaved exactly like `cl.exe` did. I have seen threads referring to replacing the native `cl.exe` with one of a *different compiler version*, and it seems even that could be problematic.

The Windows version of Intel's compiler plugs into VS, though, and that's EDG-based, so you might try that. However, I don't think that's free on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to alter your .vcproj files to specify a different MSBuild task instead of cl.exe. You can find more information about this on the MSDN website, but it's perfectly possible to launch a third party tool.

Comment: Give more details maybe? I'd like to hear a bit more on that.

Comment: @Poni: I don't really know that much about it - failed to make anything happen on my own. You'll have to check MSDN.